# Printing next to other outputs in python NO MODULES

Tags: python, printing, format

I am trying to print outputs of each of the list next to each-other.
Unfortunately I can only print the outputs of each list underneath one another.

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
            ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goosee']]
            

for i in tableData:
    new_list_i = []
    word_list_i = []
    for word in i:
        new_list_i.append(len(word))
        word_list_i.append(word)
    #print(word_list_i)
    max_per_i = max(new_list_i)
    #print(max_per_i)
    
    for b in word_list_i:
        print((((b).rjust(max_per_i))))
```

How can I fix it? My format would be 4X3 and I am trying not to use an actual table, numpy or any other module.

Thanks in advance, I am sure it's something simple for someone with experience.

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
            ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goosee']]

for i in range(len(tableData[0])):
    print(
            tableData[0][i],
            tableData[1][i],
            tableData[2][i],
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with converting to numpy array, consider this:

```
print(np.array(tableData).flatten())
```